# What is the intended way (or a good way) to do collision detection in Qt3D?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, game-development, qt3d

I have some 3d objects in a simple Qt3D scene with a camera. It is set up in a few minutes in Qt3D **using C++**. What is the best way to do collision detection? I am not asking how to do collision detection, but what the best way is to do it in Qt3D.

I changed the question from the best way - to intended way ! This is an entity component system, and the question is related to the architecture of Qt3D that is not that simple to understand in terms of where to add this. KDABs talk about an intended way, ... what is that way??

**Added may 15:**

I am using C++, not QML.

From comments and answers, it seems to be clear that the intended way is to add collision detection in aspects.

If this is correct, then how can you for example maintain a list of colliding objects in aspects ?? seems impossible to me... hope someone have an idea.

**** Added may 23 ****

Collision detection was included in Qt3D before, many things was taken out, and Qt3D was redesigned. There are many problems with lacking documentation as a result. Please do not reply to this if you do not really know the inner workings of Qt3D, I am not looking for the short answers you can google yourself to, but the deeper understanding, due to the problem with lacking documentation of the new way things work from KDAB.

Comment: "best way" is wrong form of question for SO, not unlike how. There is no criteria of "best way". Qt3D requires to buildup collision architecture from ground up. All that you're spared of (in not quite effective way) is some math

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I just noticed qt3d changed a lot. Last time I used it, it was just a way of embedding opengl in a qt window.

Comment: The issue for me, is to understand the intended way.... in other words how the developers at KDAB is intending this architcture to be used, where to hoock in our collision detection. Many videos and documentation talk about how this can be done so effectively and good, but I can not find anything on how they actually intent it to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Qt3D uses an Entity Component System (ECS), and typically in such systems entities are collections of components, and there exist systems that operate over entities based on their contents. Qt3D is no different, your QML scripts define entities and associates components to them, and Qt3D's predefined systems operate over and manipulate them to create the intended user interface experience, this is where most tutorials for Qt3D end, some will continue to mention that there are ways to build on top of the Qt3D.

Qt3D's predefined systems can be complemented with new systems, in Qt3D these systems are called Aspects. To extend Qt3D with new Aspects, for example physics simulation, you have to define a new Aspect that wraps the implementation of the system, and custom components that encapsulate whatever data necessary for the Aspect to operate that can't otherwise be associated with the entity. Once you have this all defined, and registered into the Qt3D context, you just have to populate your entities with the components the system requires and the Aspect will be called to operate over them, causing the implementation to operate over and manipulate them.

Now the remaining question is how to implement a physics (or any entity pairing based) system in an ECS, which has been covered ubiquitously in ECS game designing discussions. Below I've provided slides and blogs from KDAB providing a high velocity crash course in the Qt3D architecture and reasoning behind it, and a tutorial explaining the ins and outs of extending Qt3D with a custom aspect. Good Luck!

Slides: 
https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/qt3d-in-depth.pdf
Detail: 
https://www.kdab.com/overview-qt3d-2-0-part-1/
https://www.kdab.com/overview-qt3d-2-0-part-2/
Tutorial: 
https://www.kdab.com/writing-custom-qt-3d-aspect/
https://www.kdab.com/writing-custom-qt-3d-aspect-part-2/
Addendum: Unfortunately, there appears to be a missing 3rd part :(

Comment: This did not get me much further I am afraid, as you pointed out the vital part 3 is missing !! This seems to be KDAB strategy, they always leave out something, so that you can not figure it out on your own. I tried to call them, but they ask insane amounts of money to help out. At least it is clear that we are supposed to add collision detection in aspects.... but all objects could collide, so a list of colliding objects... in aspects ?? beats me..

Comment: Admittedly, the walk through tutorial part 3 is missing, however the high level explanation is there, and complete. In short, the aspect will have an internal representation of the subgraph of all entities that meet it's criteria. It can operate freely among them, and the modifications to it's internet representation will generate proposed manipulations to the actual scene graph.

Essentially, the aspect will modify a physics simulation to represent the current state of the scene, run the simulation, and then apply modification to it's internal representation, and propose the modifications.

Comment: Additionally, the default aspects are open source. Qt3DRenderer and Qt3DInput are the two that are most references in the material I linked, but there are plenty in the Qt3D src directory, if you check out the Qt source. Pretty much anything with a "Frontend" and "Backend" subdirectory is probably an Aspect.

Comment: Veracity, I've heard part 3 will be put up soon. Sean Harmer, the author, responded to me saying it fell to the wayside, but he assures the series will be completed. Could you be so kind as to mark this as the answer, because it's all the answer that there is to have, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sean Harmer said the same to me 1 year ago, but part 3 is NOT added, and the documentation that he promised me would be updated several years ago, is still exactly the same. The problem I am having is that aspects seem to be usable for many things, but how to use it for collision detection is a mystery... or fake advertisement.

Comment: That's a miracle, since part 2 was uploaded last December, not even a year ago. How could you have been waiting several years, for documentation on Qt3D aspects from QT3D 2.0, indeed Qt3D 1.0 was new for QT version 5.7 released in June 2016. Which gives you a grand total of maybe 2 years you could have possibly been waiting for any documentation on Qt3D. (http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/16/introducing-qt-3d/)

The documentation I have linked is sufficient for your needs. There are even example aspects in the Qt Source Code as I mention above. This is the best answer you'll get.

Comment: 1) You don't even touch on collision detection, not even your  links touch on the topic. 2) several years was referring to Qt3D documentation not the article. 3)  Qt3D is older than 2 years, your article is not saying what you think it is telling you.... 4) Sean Harmers promised me documentation, but even after a year its not delivered... so if you said he said soon article 3 will be there...it means nothing.

Comment: Sean Harmer posted Introduction to Qt3D 2.0 back in 2014, so I really don't like what you are insinuating, and that you misinform people that version 1.0 came out in June 2016.... now your info is the true miracle, some sort of time warp....

Comment: Your question was what is the intended way to add collision detection. I gave you the answer: you're supposed to extend qt3d with an aspect that will do the collision detection between entities. I'm not going to spoon feed you an implementation. You can very easily look up the myriad resources that exist on collision detection. If you asked directly "how to do collision detection" this would be a duplicate question, or thrown out for asking for  implementations. That's not what stack overflow is for.

Comment: If you bother to read all the materials and think about what you read. You should be able to work out what to do. This is all the answer you'll get. Anyone who bothers to read our exchange will not be inclined to offer you help, because you're not grateful for help given, and what is more you're entitled. You think I should give you a detailed tutorial on exactly what you're doing? Do you have any pride as a developer? Can you program? Or do you just follow tutorials without comprehending what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171589/discussion-between-veracity-and-steamythepunk).

Comment: Revisiting this year's later, part 3 of that tutorial was infact, never released. Qt3D's ECS appears to have little usage outside of industrial applications likely implemented with direct support and potentially explicit instruction from the QT3D team. It is a shame, it appears that QT has practically abandoned documenting how to leverage the ECS directly.